# nivoslider inside channel tags

Tags: ee2

I haven't found a question that i could relate to, so please bear with me.

Using a nivo jquery slider inside a channel loop continually runs on my page. Is there any way to limit and cycle it back to what is already processed? I have set the limit parameter.
It starts off how many entries that are present. After every time it goes to load a slice, it doesn't stop/cycle to where it started. Any tips?

Comment: This sounds like it's more of a JS issue than an EE one...and even more specific to Nivo itself. Nivo loops by default however so I'd imagine it's just the JS configuration that's off.

Comment: function f.expr.filters.hidden, jquery-1.6.js line 18. This what im getting in my console. Do you have any tips to point me in the right direction? JS is not my strong suit

Comment: Post your code as that would help us see what kinds of things could be causing your issue.

Comment: <div id="slider">{exp:channel:entries channel="properties" dynamic="no" limit="10" disable="categories|member_data|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}{main_photo}<img src="{photo:slider}" alt="" title="<strong>{property_address}</strong><span>{rooms} rooms,{bathrooms} Baths,{beds} beds, House size:{house_size} sq.ft.; Price $ {price}; </span>">                

                              {/main_photo}
                 {/exp:channel:entries} </div>
   http://resolutioninvestments.net/assets/js/jquery-1.6.js--http://resolutioninvestments.net/assets/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js

Comment: Any insight on the problem?